# how to put MKAnnotation without affecting the MKMapView performance

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have more than 2800 locations to be put on my map.
But when i am putting them the map is freezing. i can do nothing but wait until all the annotation data is available.

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool_mr = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:");
        NSLog(@"latitude: %f, longitude: %f", regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"latitudeDelta: %f, longitudeDelta: %f", regionsMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta, regionsMapView.region.span.longitudeDelta);

        if (regionsMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta < 0.007) {
            NSLog(@"SHOW ANNOTATIONS");
            NSArray *annotations = [regionsMapView annotations];  
            AddressAnnotation *annotation = nil; 
            for (int i=0; i<[annotations count]; i++)
            {
                NSLog(@"%i", i);
                annotation = (AddressAnnotation*)[annotations objectAtIndex:i];
                [[regionsMapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:NO];
            }
        }else {
            NSLog(@"HIDE ANNOTATIONS");
            NSArray *annotations = [regionsMapView annotations];  
            AddressAnnotation *annotation = nil; 
            for (int i=0; i<[annotations count]; i++)
            {
                NSLog(@"%i", i);
                annotation = (AddressAnnotation*)[annotations objectAtIndex:i];
                [[regionsMapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:YES];
            }

        }
    [pool_mr release];
}
```

And the Another method is like below:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation, AddressAnnotation>) annotation {    
    //NSAutoreleasePool *pool5 = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){
        NSLog(@"MKUserLocation");
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"mapView:viewForAnnotation>>>");
        NSLog(@"%@", [annotation markerColor]);
        NSLog(@"image: %@", [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"MKPinAnnotationView_%@.png",[annotation markerColor]]);
        MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:[annotation markerColor]] autorelease];
        //annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        UIImage *annotationImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"MKPinAnnotationView_%@.png",[annotation markerColor]]] autorelease];

        annView.image = annotationImage;
        annView.animatesDrop = NO;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        //annView.draggable = NO;
        //annView.highlighted = NO;

        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
        return annView;
    }

    //[pool5 release];
    NSLog(@"<<<mapView:viewForAnnotation");

    return nil;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that number of annotations, I would cluster them so as you zoom in, you get more detail. I put several thousand on a map that way and it works a treat. There is lots of information about map pin clustering if you search for it.

Here's one [commercial option](http://getsuperpin.com/) for example (no connection, haven't used) but if you look around you'll see plenty of information on how to implement it yourself.